# Colored sub and super-scripts are misaligned

Tags: color, subscripts

The title basically describes the problem. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
   $$X_{\color{red}{135}}^{\color{cyan}{345}}$$
\end{document}
```

When I compile this, the 135 is down and to the left of the 345, rather than directly below it. I get the same issue when I use `color` instead of `xcolor`. Any fixes?

Comment: See also (`aftergroup` usage) [weird placement of sub-index when color is used - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625667/weird-placement-of-sub-index-when-color-is-used) and [tex core - how does xcolor's \color work? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338702/how-does-xcolors-color-work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `\textcolor{<color>}{<text>}` works. Despite the name `\text...` it actually doesn't change to text mode so the content is still typeset as math.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
   \[ X_{\textcolor{red}{135}}^{\textcolor{cyan}{345}} \]
\end{document}
```

Note that `\color` doesn't take a second argument. The `{135}` or `{345}` behind it is just taken as following material.
You should also not use `$$` in LaTeX documents. See [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/2975).

Answer (score 4):

A workaround: use another pair of braces

```
  \[ X_{{\color{red}{135}}}^{{\color{cyan}{345}}}\]
```

It probably is some sort of grouping issue.

Comment: Good point. The `{ }` around the numbers however aren't necessary.. They are not read as argument.

Comment: I just had a look at the definition of `xcolor`s definition of `\textcolor` and all what it does is basically call `\leavevmode{\color{<color>}<text>}`, so our two answers are leading to the same :-)