# how does xcolor's \color work?

Tags: color, tex-core

Out of curiosity I looked up the code for `\color` in the [`xcolor`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor?lang=en) library.  And I found this:

```
\long\def\color@b@x#1#2#3%
 {\leavevmode
  \setbox\z@\hbox{\kern\fboxsep{\set@color#3}\kern\fboxsep}%
  \dimen@\ht\z@\advance\dimen@\fboxsep\ht\z@\dimen@
  \dimen@\dp\z@\advance\dimen@\fboxsep\dp\z@\dimen@
  {#1{#2\color@block{\wd\z@}{\ht\z@}{\dp\z@}\box\z@}}}
```

the main line that seems relevant is the last line:

```
#1{#2\color@block{\wd\z@}{\ht\z@}{\dp\z@}\box\z@}}
```

It seems this is just a another function call to another color.

---

Reading the docs a bit more I think `\color` is defined here:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\color
 {\@ifnextchar[\@undeclaredcolor\@declaredcolor}
```

and then it gets complicated with two internal functions  If the next character is `[` it does one thing or else it does the other:

```
\def\@undeclaredcolor[#1]#2%
 {\begingroup
  \let\@@cls\@empty
  \XC@getmodclr12{#1}{#2}{}%
   {\ifblendcolors
      \ifx\colorblend\@empty\else
        \edef\@@mix{\expandafter\@gobble\colorblend}\@tempswafalse
        \XC@coremodel\@@mod\@@clr\@xcolor@{}{}\@@mod\@@clr
      \fi
    \fi
    \ifconvertcolorsU
      \edef\@@tmp{\XC@tgt@mod{\@@mod}}%
      \convertcolorspec\@@mod\@@clr\@@tmp\@@clr \let\@@mod\@@tmp
    \fi
    \ifmaskcolors
      \convertcolorspec\@@mod\@@clr\XC@mmod\@@clr
      \let\@@mod\XC@mmod
      \XC@inflate\@@mod\XC@mclr\@@clr\@@tmp
      \expandafter\XC@mul\@@tmp,\@@clr
    \fi
    \edef\@@tmp{\noexpand\XC@undeclaredcolor{\@@mod}{\@@clr}}%
    \expandafter\endgroup\@@tmp}}
```

and another function for declared colors:

```
\def\@declaredcolor#1%
 {\XC@edef\XC@@tmp{#1}\XC@@tstfalse
  \ifcase\XC@type\XC@@tmp\relax \XC@@tsttrue\or \relax\else
    \ifblendcolors\XC@@tsttrue\fi \ifmaskcolors\XC@@tsttrue\fi
    \ifconvertcolorsU\XC@@tsttrue\fi
  \fi
  \ifXC@@tst
    \expandafter\XC@declaredcolor\else
    \expandafter\XC@declaredc@lor\fi}
```

I merely want to understand how someting like `{\color{blue!50!white} this is blue!}` can be written manually

Comment: What do you mean 'manually'? The aim of the code in the end is to get to the appropriate special(s) depending on the engine in use. You can do that, of course, but most people regard it as rather tedious!

Comment: Also, `xcolor` has all of the mix-in business: perhaps we might start with the 'basic' `color` package version?

Comment: @JosephWright absolutely! i don't know a lot of how the TeX macros work, but since there are certain affects that I have found difficult to achieve, I have started learning all the sources myself.  brb

Comment: This is tagged `tex-core` but core TeX doesn't do colour at all, does it? Or am I mistaken about this? @JosephWright

Comment: how is it putting color then? i type this text command and the letters are suddenly blue. i am asking how this is done

Comment: @cfr I see your point (as we both know this is driver not TeX supported), but particularly given pdfTeX's primitive support for colours, I think 'stretching' [tag:tex-core] to the driver specials is probably allowed here.

Comment: Speaking of xcolor definitions, I've always wondered why `\textcolor` is defined as `macro:#1{->\@textcolor {#1}{`, i.e. why it uses the `#{` parameter syntax instead for two ordinary, undelimited arguments.

Comment: @siracusa because in 1993 saving a couple of bytes was important...

Comment: @siracusa isn't the `#1` suppose to hold a possible `[optional]`  argument ? is seems from brief check that `\textcolor` will hand over to `\color` the check and handling for potential optional argument.

Comment: @jfbu Ah, looks like you're right. That's an interesting trick.

Answer (score 16):

There are different aspects to this question, broadly:

- How colour is implemented in TeX at a low level
- How the `color` package macros converts a user level colour instruction into a low-level colour command
- How the `xcolor` package extends `color` to give 'mix ins' and related effects

I'll tackled these areas separately. The question asks us about the user-level construct

```
{\color{blue!50!white} this is blue!}
```

and I will therefore use this or the simplified version

```
{\color{blue} this is blue!}
```

in the answer.

---

At a low level, TeX itself does not support colour at all. Rather, it leaves it to the driver, *via* the `\special` primitive and whatever form of special the driver requires. In a modern TeX set up, the drivers we tend to worry about are direct PDF production (pdfTeX/LuaTeX), `dvips` for the PostScript route from pdfTeX and `(x)dvipdfmx` for XeTeX and the DVI-to-PDF route from pdfTeX.

Each driver has it's own instruction and it's own colour notation to track. I'm going to focus on direct PDF production using pdfTeX for the answer. It has a primitive called `\pdfcolorstack` which needs a colour stack number and a colour description as greyscale, RGB or CMKY values. As we'll end up later with RGB, I'll go with that form:

```
\pdfcolorstack 0 push {0 0 1 rg 0 0 1 RG}
<Text here>
\pdfcolorstack 0 pop
```

will make the text blue. As you'll see, there are two colours to set in direct PDF mode: background and foreground. That's no universal so other driver code has to track such things 'by hand'. Also notice that the RGB values are given out of 100%, so here we've got full blue but no red or green.

---

That variability in driver code and the rather non-memorable form of colours is the reason most people rely on abstraction by the `color` package or a successor. If we use `\tracingall` with the `color` package we find that `\color` first looks for an optional `[`. As described in the [`color` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/color), the optional argument is a colour model, so one might have

```
\color[rgb]{0,0,1}
```

to specify blue without having pre-defined it. In the case where the optional argument is *not* found, the internal macro `\@declaredcolor` is chosen. It looks for a pre-defined colour specification with awkward name `\\color@<argument>`, so for us `\\color@blue`. Assuming that is found, it then uses that (which here is defined as `0 0 1 rg 0 0 1 RG`) and writes the same low-level line as before.

The definitions of colours and the exact actions to take with them are defined by various driver-dependent files, so the same mechanism will give the correct underlying instruction for pdfTeX in PDF mode and classical `dvips` even though they need different low-level forms.

---

The `xcolor` package extends the above by allowing 'mix ins', where two or more colours are combined. Taking our `blue!50!white` example, this means we end up with the low-level instruction

```
\pdfcolorstack 0 push {0.5 0.5 1 rg 0.5 0.5 1 RG}
```

Notice that this is a linear combination of blue (`0 0 1`) and white (`1 1 1`). Using `\tracingall` you'll find that there is a lot more to 'do' here than in the `color` case. Fundamentally, though, what has to be done is

- Grab the two arguments as before (optional `[<model>]` and mandatory `<color spec>`)
- Assuming no `<model>`, break up the `<color spec>` into named colours and amounts
- Do the maths to make the requested linear combination
- Write the appropriate low-level code

Comment: The argument parsing, value look up and maths is 'lots of standard TeX programming', which it's hard to put into one short-ish focussed answer!

Answer (score 15):

The code you show at the top is the internals for `\colorbox` setting a box with a background colour which is why it calls `\color` internally. Other than that it is pretty hard to answer your question in this generality. The whole point of color and xcolor packages is to take a consistent user input and then generate whatever needs to be generated to produce color, so it depends if you are using dvips or dvipdfm or pdftex or xetex or ... different code is generated in each case.  Start with `texdoc color.dtx` and read the documented sources of the `color` package, `xcolor` uses the same basic framework but vastly extended with the mixing syntax and more colour models.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\showoutput
{\color{blue!50!white} this is blue!}

\end{document}
```

with pdftex will show that that colour is achieved by

```
...\pdfcolorstack 0 push {0.5 0.5 1 rg 0.5 0.5 1 RG}
...\glue(\topskip) 3.05556
...\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x345.0, glue set 279.33325fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 t
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 h
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 i
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 s
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 i
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 s
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 b
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 l
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 u
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 !
....\pdfcolorstack 0 pop
```

so

```
\pdfcolorstack 0 push {0.5 0.5 1 rg 0.5 0.5 1 RG}
```

and

```
\pdfcolorstack 0 pop
```

but if you just use the primitives nested latex colours would not work, and of course the document would only work with pdftex not latex+dvips or xetex etc.
Dissasembling the output isn't the best way, both color and xcolor have fully documented sources if you need the full details.

Comment: I had once an issue (using dvipdfmx driver) and I concluded `color` was lacking some interface. `\set@color` will do `\special {pdf:bcolor \current@color }\aftergroup \reset@color `. In my context creating a group was no option. I ended up using directly `\special{pdf:bcolor  OrangeRed}` and `\special{pdf:ecolor}`. There (afaict) is _no interface_ for this in `color`. Issue:  iterate `\color{blue} A\par` many times (129 times) then then dvipdfmx will complain `dvipdfmx:warning: Color stack overflow. Just ignore.` and colours will get wrong after that in the pdf document.

Comment: in fact 127 times are enough in a minimal `article` document with page numbering (it produces 3 pages, and the third page number gets contaminated by the colour), now that I tested again. An interface of the type `\startcolor/\stopcolor`, not using groups, seems to be lacking.

Comment: the reported issue regards also xetex.

Comment: @jfbu well yes the code in xdvipdfmx and dvipdfmx is probably the same here.