# weird placement of sub-index when color is used

Tags: color

Could anyone explain why the sub-indexes were placed not at their correct positions when color is used? [image]

With some further experiments I found that the problem can be fixed by surrounding the sub-indexes with more {}, but why without the extra {} the code does not produce correct output?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\dint}{\displaystyle \int}
\begin{document}
\[
\dint_1^e \frac{\ln x}{x} dx =
\dint^{\color{red} \ln e}_{\color{red} \ln 1} u ~du       %buggy  
=\dint_{\color{cyan}{\ln 1}}^{\color{cyan}{\ln e}} u ~du  %buggy
= \dint^{\ln e}_{\ln 1} u ~du           %without using color, it works fine 
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: use `^{{\color{red} \ln e}}` or `^{\textcolor{\color{red} \ln e}}`

Comment: yes I knew adding more {} can fix the problem,  but without the extra {} the code does not seem to have obvious bug. so I was interested in knowing why  without the extra {} it would not work as expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Colored sub and super-scripts are misaligned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16369/colored-sub-and-super-scripts-are-misaligned)

Answer (score 2):

`\color` works by setting a node which inserts the color using a backend-specific code. It then inserts via `\aftergroup` a node which restores the color. If you have

```
X^{\color{red} abc} _x
```

Then this ends up being

```
X^{\special{red} abc}\special{restore color} _x
```

and the subscript ends up subscripting the color restore node rather than the intended base.

Conversely with an extra group

```
X^{{\color{red} abc}} _x
```

The color restore stays in the superscript

```
    X^{{\special{red} abc}\special{restore color}} _x
```

so the subscript acts on the intended base.